# Trigger automatic emails if cell in the second of two columns is empty using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have column A with the dates samples are received and column I with when the sample was processed. I want Excel to send email weekly until column I is filled.

I tried making an "if then" statement but it doesn't work.

The first statement should say

> "if column A is not empty and column I is empty, then send email weekly"
>   "if both columns are not empty, then no email needs to be sent".

I don't necessarily need the message box but I couldn't end the program without something there.

I tried to make the body of the code to then figure out the automation later.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A:A")
Set rng2 = Range("I:I")

For Each Value In rng1
If rng1.Text <> "" And rng2.Text = "" Then
    Dim aOutlook As Object
    Dim aEmail As Object
    Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
    Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    aEmail.Importance = 2
    aEmail.Subject = "You have a message from Quarantine"
    aEmail.Body = "Please complete the excel sheet for samples"
    aEmail.Recipients.Add "me@email.com"
    aEmail.Send

ElseIf rng1.Text <> "" And rng2.Text <> "" Then MsgBox "All projects are up to date"
ElseIf rng1.Text = "" Then
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The key with an issue like this is simplify the code so that only the problem section of code is remaining. See **hoe to create a [mcve]** as well as "[ask]" and also [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from the site's top user.

Comment: I'm not sure if by "it doesn't work" you mean it doesn't give the **expected results** or that it errors out and won't run. However, if it errors out, it may be because of the combination of single-line if-statement with a multi-line if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `For Each` loop you need to make sure you're referencing the variable that you're iterating - in your case, that was `Value`, which you forgot to do. For the sake of your code I've replaced `Value` with `myval` - I wouldn't recommend using `Value` as a variable name, since it's used so much in syntax, you're going to end up confusing yourself.

No need for `rng2` - just use `.Offset` to check the value in column I.

You also needed a way to exit your loop when you've run out of lines - otherwise you're iterating over a million rows for no reason.

I've also removed the declarations that you weren't using, and moved the other ones **outside** your loop to the top of the subroutine. Declare them once and be done with it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range, myval As Range, rngeAddresses As Range
Dim aOutlook As Object, aEmail As Object

Set rng1 = Range("A:A")

For Each myval In rng1

    'Check column A and column I
    If myval.Text <> "" And myval.Offset(0, 8).Text = "" Then

        Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        aEmail.Importance = 2
        aEmail.Subject = "You have a message from Quarantine"
        aEmail.Body = "Please complete the excel sheet for samples"
        aEmail.Recipients.Add "me@email.com"
        'aEmail.Send

    ElseIf myval.Text = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

Next

End Sub
```